# Are $\int_0^{\infty } t f(t) e^{-r t} \, dt$ and $\int_0^{\infty } e^{-r t} \int_t^{\infty } f(s) e^{-r (s-t)} \, ds \, dt$ always equal?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am comparing

$\int_0^{\infty } t f(t) e^{-r t} \, dt$

and

$\int_0^{\infty } e^{-r t} \int_t^{\infty } f(s) e^{-r (s-t)} \, ds \, dt.$

Assuming that $r>0$ and $f(t)$ is intergrable and converages.

I can only show that they are equal for some specific simple examples of $f(t)$.

Comment: They are equal. Interchange the integrals on the right to get a proof.

Answer (score 0):

The equality can be be shown with integration by parts as follows

\begin{align}
&\int_0^{\infty } e^{-r t} \int_t^{\infty } f(s) e^{-r (s-t)} \, ds \, dt\\
=& \int_0^{\infty } \int_t^{\infty } f(s) e^{-rs} \, ds \, dt\\
=& \ t \int_t^{\infty } f(s) e^{-rs}ds\bigg|_{0}^{\infty}
 - \int_0^\infty t \ \frac d{dt}\left( \int_t^{\infty } f(s) e^{-rs} \, ds\right)\ dt\\
= &\ 0 + \int_0^{\infty } t f(t) e^{-r t} \, dt
\end{align}